# Oracle SQL Saying NULL instead of 0 (ZERO)

Tags: sql, oracle, null, zero

I have a query where it is subtracting from two columns and then dividing to generate a percentage complete. If the area hasn't been started it propduces NULL I would like it to instead show 00 or 0.

Here is my Query:

```
substr(count(process_locations.count_attempt_id)/count(processes.process_id),2,2) as "Percentage Complete"
```

I have try NVL, and COALESE, but am unsure where to place them I have tried a few combinations, but i Receive errors.

I have also tried a CASE WHEN ELSE END, but it still said null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:-

```
NVL(substr(count(process_locations.count_attempt_id)/count(processes.process_id),2,2),0) as "Percentage Complete"
```

Comment: Hmm.. This does produce a result, but now everything says NULL.

Comment: @Spartacus38:- Updated my answer now! Please check

Comment: This appears to work, unfortunately I have nothing that has ZERO now in my DB nothing with the code, just we've now counted something >.< this appears to work. I'll mark this as complete unless something changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, an unpopulated "area" is null unless the field is specified as "not null." If you have permissions, you might want to do that. Otherwise use [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) to substitute any NULLS with zeros.